# next().focus() only works for controls of same type

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to make Enter-key in forms move focus to the next control. I got several textboxes, checkboxes and buttons. They all got class='ctrl'.
This code does most of the trick.

```js
$(document).on('keydown', '.ctrl', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==13) {
      $(this).next().focus();
    }
})
```

```css
.ctrl {
  display:block 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="ctrl" type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<input class="ctrl" type="text" id="mname" name="mname">
<input class="ctrl" type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
<input class="ctrl" id="check1" type="checkbox">Select 1
<input class="ctrl" id="check2" type="checkbox">Select 2
<input class="ctrl" id="check3" type="checkbox">Select 3
<button type="button" class="ctrl" ;">Done</button>
```

But if a textbox got the focus, it only jumps to other textboxes. If a checkbox got the forcus, it only jump to other checkboxes and so on. I would like et to behave as the TAB-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get index of `class` where keypress event has taken place then add `1` to it to get next index of same class then use  `$(this).closest('div').find('.ctrl:eq(' + index + ')')` to focus next inputs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('keydown', '.ctrl', function(e) {
  var length = $(".ctrl").length //get length
  var index = $(".ctrl").index(this) + 1; //get index of class
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  //if index is less
    if (index < length) {
      //get closest div find class with same index
      $(this).closest('div').find('.ctrl:eq(' + index + ')').focus();
    } else {
    //focus first input
    $(this).closest('div').find('.ctrl:eq(0)').focus();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="ctrl" type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  <input class="ctrl" type="text" id="mname" name="mname">
  <input class="ctrl" type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
  <input class="ctrl" id="check1" type="checkbox">Select 1
  <input class="ctrl" id="check2" type="checkbox">Select 2
  <input class="ctrl" id="check3" type="checkbox">Select 3
  <button type="button" class="ctrl">Done</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant Swati Thank you. This always works. What I also discovered was, that if I remove <br> tags, it also worked.

Comment: Glad i helped :) . I have added condition as well if focus reaches last input and if user press enter again it will point to first input like tab key does .